# How do I declare an array in bluej?

Tags: java, arrays, bluej, declare

```
  private Piece[][] board;

 public cboard(){
      this.board = new Piece[8][8];
    }

  public  boolean isEmpty(int x, int y){
      boolean empty= true;
        if (board[x][y] != null){
          empty= false;
        }
      return empty;
 }
 public void placePiece(Piece, int x, int y){
     if(isEmpty(x, y)){
        board[x][y] = piece;
     }
 }
}
```

Will this create an array for the pieces?
The function has to check wether or not the place is empty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your constructor you create the array correctly.
By default, Java will fill the array with `null` values but it knows that they are supposed to be `Piece` objects.

So your `isEmpty` method should work because it tests for `null`. However you might need a method to *remove* the `Piece` again and set the entry in the array back to `null` – otherwise your `isEmpty` would only work at the beginning.

just a hint: 
you can break down your `isEmpty` method to only one line. It returns a `boolean` and the test in your if `board[x][y] != null` results in a `boolean` as well.
So all you need is `return board[x][y]==null;`

One last thing:  `cboard` should begin with a capital letter, like all classes in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The preceding program declares an array (named anArray) with the following line of code:

// declares an array of integers
int[] anArray;

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html